# British Passenger with less than 2 months valid passport transiting in Dubai and leaving through Abu Dhabi next day

Tags: transit, passports, uk-citizens, dubai, abu-dhabi

I am a British citizen but my passport is expiring two months from Today. I will travel to the UK via UAE. My flight to the UAE is through Dubai but my connecting flight to London is Etihad Airways which leaves only from Abu Dhabi 24 hours later. I will therefore need to enter Dubai and travel to Abu Dhabi by car. British Citizens are normally given visas on arrival at the airport but due to the 2 months validity on the passport I am a bit worried. Can anyone please advice if that is Ok.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Embassy of the United Arab Emirates in London site](http://www.uae-embassy.ae/embassies/uk/content/591), I found the following:

> UK Citizens - Visit Visa
>
> Citizens of the UK (with right of abode in the UK) will be granted a free of charge visit visa on arrival in the UAE. No application in advance of travel is necessary. Please note that your passport will be stamped for 30 days upon arrival. If further stay is required an application for an extension should be made to the local General Directorate of Residency and Foreign Affairs three days prior to the expiry date (chargeable services).

It does not mention the required time left before expiration of your passport. It does mention different rules for British Overseas Territories people without right of abode and for British Diplomatic and Official Passport holders but if the above quoted paragraph fits you, it should apply.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a problem, but you should make absolutely sure you carry proof of your further travel with you.

Your visa is free - but you still have to abide by the normal rules for visa on arrival which is three months validity on your passport; however as you are traveling onward this may be waived as you would probably be considered a transit passenger.

Oh, you also don't need a hotel reservation (despite what it says on the form).